# How do I make custom iOS controls for Visual Studio storyboard

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

Is it possible to create and use custom controls in the storyboard designer for Visual Studio? I have created a test-component as such:

```
[Register("Test")]
[Category("Controls")]
public class Test : UIView
{
    public Test()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public Test(IntPtr handle)
        : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public override void Draw(RectangleF rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);
        var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();

        context.SetFillColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1f);
        context.FillRect(new RectangleF(0, 0, 50, 50));
    }
}
```

This works fine in Xamarin Studio on my mac, but I cannot get it to work in Visual Studio. I cannot seem to get it to register the view into the toolbox. Is there any way to make this work? If not, how can the component be added in code?

Comment: Did ever get a solution to this?

Comment: No, I switched to working on the Mac instead.

Comment: As have I :-) Xcode or XS on Mac?